# cordova Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'verifyPhoneNumber' of undefined

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I develope cordova mobile app. and we send otp to phone no. so we used firebase plugin to send otp and i go through this guidlines [fcm plugin](https://github.com/apptum/cordova-plugin-firebase#verifyphonenumber-android-only).

I installed this plugin

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.21 --save

I have this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'verifyPhoneNumber' of undefined

```
window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber("+91*********", timeOutDuration, function(credential) {
        console.log(credential);

           console.log('successfully login with phone no');
                    alert('successfully login')
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

from: https://javebratt.com/firebase-phone-authentication/

*Jorge Vergara Mod  Ankit Maheshwari • 3 months ago*
You need to add the plugin from the repo, if you use the name you're adding the official plugin that doesn't have the functionality yet.
https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase